# Why does my Access-Control-Allow-Origin header have an incorrect value?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, cors, cross-domain

I have a webpage on the domain https://imeet.pgi.com making an XMLHttpRequest to another domain. The request fails with the following console error (using Chrome browser):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://pgidrive.com/eloqua/forminator/getForm.php. The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'https://imeet.pgi.coms' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
>   Origin 'https://imeet.pgi.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Note that the Access-Control-Allow Origin header has a value of:
**https://imeet.pgi.coms** with an "s" on the end.

Why does my `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header have this incorrect value?

If it could be a typo somewhere, where would I look to check?

More background info: I have made this same request successfully from other domains with no issue. I have set a list of allowed origin domains that includes imeet.pgi.com on the .htaccess file on pgidrive.com.

Also, the code for the allowed origin domains in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(agenday.com|imeet.pgi.com|pgi.com|go.pgi.com|staging.pgi.com|imeetlive.pgi.com|globalmeet.pgi.com|latam.pgi.com|br.pgi.com|pgi.ca)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

Comment: check that htaccess file then

Comment: @hjpotter92 - I checked the htaccess, but I don't see a problem. I just added my htaccess code to my post. Thank you very much for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your htaccess file, when doing the following:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(agenday.com|imeet.pgi.com|pgi.com|go.pgi.com|staging.pgi.com|imeetlive.pgi.com|globalmeet.pgi.com|latam.pgi.com|br.pgi.com|pgi.ca)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
```

you have `AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1`. Here, `$0` means the whole matched string, and `$1` means the first matched group. The first matched group here is `(s)?`.

When you make a request using the origin: `https://imeet.pgi.com`, the pattern is parsed and grouped [as follows](https://www.regex101.com/r/PhreQJ/1):

> ```
> $0 = `https://imeet.pgi.com`
> $1 = `s`
> $3 = `imeet.pgi.com`
> ```

which is why you see the `s` character.

Change that to (basically, remove the `$1`):

```
SetEnvIf Origin "https?://(?:(?:agenday|(?:(?:imeet|go|staging|imeetlive|globalmeet|latam|br)\.)?pgi)\.com|pgi\.ca)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
```

Comment: DUDE. You are the man. Thank you so much! I'm new to regular expressions and patterns - I see I still have a lot to learn!